# Complex recursive function call with multiple setTimeouts (clearing issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, timer

I've created a function that animates between tiles which I'd like to pause on hover.

Here's a basic overview of how it works: there are 3 tiles which are beside each other that cycle through their own dinstinct sets of tiles, on hover that particular tile should pause, and then when moused out it should resume.

In the code, there's a timer in which a class is added to the tile which animates it and appends the next tile to it. Then, inside this timer, another setTimeout is created which removes the animation class, removes the tile that was just shown and shows the tile that just got appended. Then, there's a final setTimeout which recursively calls the function again with all the same passed parameters (so it loops forever). Inside the function I have events binded which watch for mouse over and mouse out on the indivual tiles. They are meant to pause the timers on hover and start it again on mouse out.

The function works as intended except the mouseout binding calling the function recursively for some reason gets called twice for 2 or 3 different tiles (1-2 of them not being the tile I hovered over) and causes weird results. Anyone know this part:

```
.one("mouseout", function () {
        animateTiles(content, tile);
    });
```

gets called multipled times with different parameters on mouseout?

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
var l_tAnimateTilesTimer = null,
l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = null,
l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = null;
function animateTiles(content, tile) {
    l_tAnimateTilesTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        appendNextTileContent(content, tile);
        tile.addClass(l_sAnimationClass);
        l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            tile.removeClass(l_sAnimationClass)
            .find(".front").remove();
            tile.find(".back").removeClass("back").addClass("front");
            l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                animateTiles(content, tile);
            }, 5000);
        }, 300);
    }, 2000);
    tile.off().one("mouseover", function () {
        if (l_tAnimateTilesTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = null;
        }
    }).one("mouseout", function () {
        animateTiles(content, tile);
    });
};
var tile = $("#tile_wrap .right");
var content = {
   title = "tile 1",
   id = "tile_1_id"
};
animateTiles(tile, content); //an example of calling it
```

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything. I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you show where you initialized the `tile` variable? Or I guess more directly, what is the value of that variable? Is it just one element?

Comment: Sure, just edited in an example of calling it. It's just a jquery dom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer if anyone's curious, I needed to move the setTimeout variable creations inside the function (so they are local to the specific function call). I also added the mouse events inside the l_tAnimateTilesTimer as well, I'm not sure if this is necessary though. This is the complete example:

```
function animateTiles(content, tile) {
var l_tAnimateTilesTimer = null,
l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = null,
l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = null;
l_tAnimateTilesTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    tile.off().one("mouseover", function () {
        if (l_tAnimateTilesTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = null;
        }
    }).one("mouseout", function () {
        animateTiles(content, tile);
    });
        appendNextTileContent(content, tile);
        tile.addClass(l_sAnimationClass);
        l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            tile.removeClass(l_sAnimationClass)
            .find(".front").remove();
            tile.find(".back").removeClass("back").addClass("front");
            l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                animateTiles(content, tile);
            }, 5000);
        }, 300);
    }, 2000);
    tile.off().one("mouseover", function () {
        if (l_tAnimateTilesTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesFlipTimer = null;
        }
        if (l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer);
            l_tAnimateTilesRecursiveTimer = null;
        }
    }).one("mouseout", function () {
        animateTiles(content, tile);
    });
};
var tile = $("#tile_wrap .right");
var content = {
   title = "tile 1",
   id = "tile_1_id"
};
animateTiles(tile, content); //an example of calling it
```

Answer (score 2):

Mouseover and mouseout will be triggered on the element or any of it's nested elements. Try to use mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

Comment: I was going to edit your answer but, I think I would be changing it to much. The event bubbles, so the parents also get the event, not its children, which is what nested elements sounds like.. just asking you to write an answer that is clearer about that

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Part of the problem I think is that I'm calling the animateTiles function for all 3 tiles... so somehow the parameters inside this function call ".one("mouseleave", function () {
        animateTiles(content, tile);
    });" are not correct, and somehow it's being called more than once (even though I'm unbinding with off() and using jquery one()